# How to create Google Workspace/Cloud Administrator account?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to set up Domain-Wide Delegation on a service account to allow a web page to interact with the Google Drive API, but the page says I need to log in with an "Administator Account". I have searched, and cannot find a page allowing me to create an Admin Account. Please let me know how to get this set up.

Answer (score 1):

In order to set domain-wide delegation you need to make sure you are using a Google Workspace account. Only Super Administrators of a Google Workspace account can configure domain-wide delegation for their organization, so you will not be able to configure this if you are not a Google Workspace Super Admin.

Note that this feature is available only for paid organization accounts and not for regular end-user accounts like gmail.com since the purpose of the feature is to provide access to the users' information from an organization to a certain app.

If you already have a Google Workspace account but you are not the Super Admin, you would need to request your admin to configure this on your behalf or request admin rights.

#### See also:

[Control API access with domain-wide delegation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en)

[Sign up for a free Google Workspace trial](https://support.google.com/a/answer/53926?hl=en&ref_topic=4388346)

[Who is my administrator?](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6208960?hl=en)